# Prove that for each subset A of X, c(A) = cl(A), where cl(A) is the closure of A in the topology T.

Tags: general-topology

Definition: Let X be a set. A closure operator on X is a function c which associates with each subset A of X a subset c(A) of X satisfying the following properties:

(1) $c(∅)=∅$

(2) $A \subseteq c(A)$

(3) $c(c(A))=c(A)$

(4) $c(A\cup B)=c(A) \cup c(B)$

for all subsets A, B of X.

A subset $A$ of $X$ is $c$-closed provided that $c(A) = A$, and a subset $B$ of $X$ is $c$-open provided that $X \setminus B$ is $c$-closed.

Assume that c is a closure operator for a given set X. Prove that for each subset A of X, c(A) = cl(A), where cl(A) is the closure of A in the topology T.

Comment: I liked you in The Blind Side.

Comment: What is the topoloty T? You haven't defined it; it is mentioned for the first time at the very end of your question.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the question correctly? For instance, defining c(A) = A for all A satisfies your axioms but is _not_ the same as the standard closure for non-closed sets. E.g. c((0,1)) = (0,1) while cl((0,1)) = [0,1] on the standard topology on the real line.